# How can I use predicate function in find_if algorithm?

Tags: c++, predicate

The predicate function:

```
bool Schedule::predicateFunc(map<pair<string,int>,pair<string,Array> >::iterator it,string &a)
{
    return (it->first).first == a;
}
```

Function which I have to use predicate func:

```
 void Schedule::studentSchedule() {
    string s,c;
    cout<<"Enter the student and course name to create schedule"<<endl;
    cin>>s>>c;
    list<string>::iterator studentLoc;
    map<pair<string,int>,pair<string,Array> >::iterator courseL;
    map<pair<string,int>,pair<string,Array> >::iterator location;

    studentLoc = find(getStudentList().begin(),getStudentList().end(),s);
    location = find_if(getMatchMap().begin(), getMatchMap().end(), predicateFunc(courseL,c) )       
    if(studentLoc != getStudentList().end() && location != getMatchMap().end())
        {
            cout<<"I found it"<<endl;
        }
        else
            cout<<"I cant found it"<<endl;
    }
```

When I tried to use predicate function in here:

```
location = find_if(getMatchMap().begin(), getMatchMap().end(), predicateFunc(courseL,c) )
```

I am getting an error like this:

```
In file included from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/algorithm:61,
                 from C:\Users\Fatih\Desktop\clion\SchoolProject1\Schedule.cpp:4:
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 'bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<_Predicate>::operator()(_Iterator) [with _Iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::array<int, 6> > > >; _Predicate = bool]':
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:104:42:   required from '_InputIterator std::__find_if(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Predicate, std::input_iterator_tag) [with _InputIterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::array<int, 6> > > >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<bool>]'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:161:23:   required from '_Iterator std::__find_if(_Iterator, _Iterator, _Predicate) [with _Iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::array<int, 6> > > >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<bool>]'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:3930:28:   required from '_IIter std::find_if(_IIter, _IIter, _Predicate) [with _IIter = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::array<int, 6> > > >; _Predicate = bool]'
C:\Users\Fatih\Desktop\clion\SchoolProject1\Schedule.cpp:25:93:   required from here
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h:283:11: error: expression cannot be used as a function
  { return bool(_M_pred(*__it)); }
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What is the true usage of the predicate funtion in here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably misunderstanding the concept of `Predicate`. It must be a function that takes one *element* of the collection and returns a `bool`. This function is now called for each element in the range until the first time it returns `true` (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Predicate)).

In your code, you're *calling* the predicate instead of passing it to `find_if`.

Also, the signature of your predicate is wrong: It takes two parameters instead of one. The signature should be

```
bool Schedule::predicateFunc(const map<pair<string,int>,pair<string,Array> >::value_type& x);
```

If you want to pass it an additional argument, e.g. a string to be compared with, you coulddo something like:

```
bool Schedule::compareName(map<pair<string,int>,pair<string,Array> >::value_type& x,string &a)
{
    return (x.first).first == a;
}
```

and then in the calling code:

```
std::string expected_name = "some name";
auto predicate = [&](auto& course) { return compareName(course, expected_name); };
location = find_if(getMatchMap().begin(), getMatchMap().end(), predicate);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are *calling* your predicate function but you must *provide a reference* to your predicate function:

```
location = find_if(getMatchMap().begin(), getMatchMap().end(), predicateFunc);
```

Also, the signature of your predicate function is not correct. It should take only one argument and this argument is not an iterator, but the value of the collection/iterator. It is probably also a good idea to make it a const-reference.

```
bool Schedule::predicateFunc(const map<pair<string,int>,pair<string,Array> >::value_type& x);
```

If you need to provide an argument to your predicate function, you have several options:

- Do not use a separate predicate function, but a lambda expression.
- Use `std::bind()`.
- Use a function object.